# My APIs are not working in Postman but works in browser | Laravel for REST | Postman v9.7.0 Native Desktop App

Tags: laravel, rest, postman, laravel-6, postman-native-app

I am developing REST APIs for my project in Laravel 6.*. The problem is that my APIs are working in Postman Chrome Extention and web browser but not in Native Desktop Application.
I'm am serving my laravel app. by using php artisan serve command. the [The error which i got in postman console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsr5r.png)
**Note :**
I'm not using Bearer Token in this API
[After adding header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXM6c.png)

Comment: do you use Bearer Token for auth?

Comment: can you give the screenshot of the headers that are you using?

Comment: According to Screenshot, You are not passing correct header token while calling API, Try to add your authorization code in the header tab of postman instead of authorization if its not working in that

share picture of postman and your config for api call

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` can't see this headers. Add this and try again

Comment: @MuhammadHabibpour Yes but not in this API.

Comment: @MuhammadHabibpour Adding this header still has not worked for me.

Comment: @Adhar Can you share your route picture as well?

Comment: Please I am experiencing this with my application. Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Buchi APIS on my personal laptop is working fine. I think it was the project-specific setup issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since it checks for the csrf tokens,according to me it is not allowing third party to access the api.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to Screenshot, You are not passing the correct header token while calling API,
Try to add your authorization code in the header tab of postman instead of in authorization.

if still, it's not working in that then share picture of postman and your config for API call

Comment: I have added a new screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You should share your postman config if you want better help.

I'd say the common culprits are :

1. Check your Bearer token.
2. Make sure you have a **content-type** header set to **application/json** if you're expecting a JSON.

Comment: I'm not using the Bearer token in this API.

Comment: I have added the screenhot.